# Python program giveing TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python

I am writing an algorithm that solves Sudoku puzzles using a backtracking algorithm when i try and run my python program it gives me an error of TypeError:cannot unpack non-iterable int object

this is the line of code the error is caused at

```
 row, col = find_empty_box(puzzle)
```

This is the full code

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], 
        [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
        [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
        [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
        [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
        [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
        [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
        [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
        [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

print (np.matrix(grid))

def find_empty_box(puzzle): 
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if puzzle[x][y] == 0:
                return x, y 
            else:
                return 0

def Answer_Valid(puzzle, guess, row, col): 
    row_values = puzzle[row]    
    if guess in row_values:
        return False

    column_values = [puzzle[i][col]for i in range(9)]
    if guess in column_values:
        return False

    row_start = (row // 3) * 3
    col_start = (col // 3) * 3

    for x in range(row_start, row_start + 3):
        for y in range(col_start, col_start + 3):
            if puzzle[x][y] == guess:
                return False

        return True

def Solver(puzzle):
    row, col = find_empty_box(puzzle)

    if row is None:
        return True

    for guess in range(1,10):
        if Answer_Valid(puzzle, guess, row, col):
            puzzle[row][col] = guess

            if Solver(puzzle):
                return True

        puzzle[row][col] = 0

    return False

print(Solver(grid))

print(np.matrix(grid))
```

Comment: It's returning an int (0 in this case) which is a non-iterable object.

Comment: hi HiddenSquid123, if You want to write code solving sudoku, then I advice You to use Prolog instead of Python. "Prolog is extremely well suited to solve combinatorial tasks like Sudoku". https://www.metalevel.at/sudoku/ If You really want to solve Sudoku using Python then you see that it is not easy task with Your current style of writing. You still lack basics and should know that code is just side-effect taken from Your: knowledge CS subjects (data structs, algos, programming langs). logical thinking, experience from "simple" (because You make it easy with chopping) tasks done. Have fun.

Comment: Returning objects of different types in different branches of a function is a recipe for bugs (as you have just discovered).

Comment: the problem is in `find_empty_box` `else return 0`,then you unpack the return `row,col = find_empty_box(puzzle)`